# What happens when we press a key on Windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, keyboard, system, cpu-architecture

First of all, I would say to you that I write this question from nothing because I have attempt to find good documentation but nothing stand out...

**What happens when we squeeze a key?**

I think this is complex but I hope you can help me.

What I search to know : all (but especially the program start on the host machine and how the key electric signal is encoded and send...)

Comment: Yeah - a lot happens, too much for an SO question:(  There is a keyboard controller, protocol, USB, interrupt, device driver, Windows messages.  Too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eXtensible Host Controller (xHC) has a Periodic Transfer Ring. Windows programs this ring to trigger a transfer every time an interval in milliseconds has passed. The right interval is specified in the USB descriptor returned by the USB device. When the transfer occurs, the xHC puts a Transfer Event TRB on the event ring and triggers an MSI-X interrupt which bypasses the IOAPIC as some kind of inter-processor interrupt. If Windows detects some change in the keys pressed, it will send a message to the application which currently has focus (calling the window's procedure) with the key pressed in one of the argument.

I don't know about electrical signals but I know the eXtensible Host Controller is the USB controller responsible to interact with USB on modern Windows systems. Since Windows nowadays requires an x64 processor, the xHC must be present on your motherboard. The xHC is a PCI-Express device which is compliant with the PCI-Express specification.

To find an xHC, you:

1. Find the RSDP ACPI table in RAM;

This table will be found by the UEFI firmware which acts as some kind of small operating-system (OS) during boot of the computer. Then, the OS developers will write a small UEFI application named bootx64.efi that they will place on a FAT32 partition on the hard-disk. They will place this app in the /boot/efi directory. The UEFI firmware will directly launch that application on boot of the computer which allows to have an OS which doesn't require user input to be launched (similarly to how it used to work with the legacy BIOS fetching the first sector of the hard-disk and executing the instructions found there).

The UEFI application is compiled in practice with either EDK2 or gnu-efi. These compilers are aware of the UEFI environment and specification. They thus compile the code to system calls that are present during boot and available for the UEFI application written by the OS developers. The System Tables (often the ACPI tables) are given as an argument to the "main" function (often called UefiMain) called by the UEFI firmware in the UEFI application. The code of the application can thus simply use these arguments to find the RSDP table and pass it to the OS.

2. Find the MCFG ACPI table using the RSDP;

The chain of table is RSDP -> XSDT -> MCFG. Once the OS found the MCFG, this table specifies the base address of the PCI configuration space. To interact with PCI devices you use memory mapped IO (MMIO). You write to some position in RAM and it will instead write to the registers of the PCI devices. The MCFG thus specifies the base address at which you will start finding MMIO registers for the different PCI devices that are plugged into the computer.

3. Iterate on the PCI devices and look at their IDs until you find an xHC.

To iterate on the PCI devices, the PCI convention specifies a formula which is the following:

```
UINT64 physical_address = base_address + ((bus - first_bus) << 20 | device << 15 | function << 12);
```

The base_address is for a specific segment group. Each segment group can have 256 buses (suitable for large servers or large computers with lots of components). There can be up to 65536 segment groups and each can have up to 256 PCI buses. Each PCI bus can have up to 32 devices plugged onto it and each device can have up to 8 functions. Each function can also be a PCI bridge. This is quite straightforward to understand because the terminology is clear. The bus here is an actual serial bus that the PCI devices (like a network card, a graphics card, an xHC, an AHCI, etc.) use to communicate with RAM. The function is a functionality of the PCI device like controlling USB devices, hard-disks, HDMI screens (for graphics cards), etc. The PCI bridge bridges a PCI bus to another PCI bus. It means you can have almost an infinite amount of devices with the PCI specification because the bridges allow to extend the tree of devices by adding other PCI host controllers.

Meanwhile, the bus is simply a number between 0 and 255. The first bus is specified in the MCFG ACPI table for a specific segment group. The device is a number between 0 and 31 and the function is a number between 0 and 7. This formula returns a physical address which points to a conventional configuration space (it is the same for all functions) which has specific registers. These registers are used to determine what is the type of device and to load a proper driver for it. Each function of each device thus gets a configuration space.

For the xHC, there will be only one function and the IDs returned by its configuration space will be 0x0C for the class ID and 0x03 for the subclass ID (https://wiki.osdev.org/EXtensible_Host_Controller_Interface).

Once you found an xHC, it gets rather complex. You need to initialize it and get the USB devices which are plugged in the computer at the current moment. You need to take several steps to get the xHC operational. For this part, I'll leave you to read the xHCI specification which (on chapter 4) specifies exactly the steps which need to be taken (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/extensible-host-controler-interface-usb-xhci.pdf).

For the keyboard portion I'll leave you to read one of my answer on the stackexchange for computer science: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141870/when-are-a-controllers-registers-loaded-and-ready-to-inform-an-i-o-operation/141918#141918.

Some good links:

https://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus

https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI